# Closing Dropdown menu with a click anywhere on page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

So far I've got the following code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="user_info">
<p>Signed in as <span>max</span></p>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
<li id="siteSelector"><a href="#" class="">Switch to&#9660;</a>
<ul>
 <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
width: 1200px;
}
#user_info {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: right;
width: 250px;
}
#user_info p {
color: #333333;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 1.6em;
}
#user_info ul {
margin-top: 5px;
}
#user_info ul li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5px 3px;
}
#user_info a {
color: #0B594A;
}
#siteSelector {
position: relative;
}
#siteSelector > a {
padding: 0 10px;
}
#siteSelector ul {
display: none;
}
#siteSelector ul li {
text-align: left;
width: 95%;
}
.siteSelect_anchor {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0B594A;
border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
color: #FFFFFF !important;
display: block;
margin-top: -5px;
padding-top: 5px !important;
text-decoration: none;
}
.siteSelect_ul {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border-color: #0B594A;
border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #666666;
display: block !important;
height: auto;
left: 0;
padding-bottom: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
width: 59px;
z-index: 250;
}
.siteSelect_ul a {
margin-left: -30px;
}
```

And JS:

```
 function clickNav() {
        $("#siteSelector").click(function() {
            $("a:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_anchor');
            $("ul:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_ul');
            $(".siteSelect_ul li").click(function(e) {
                var liTxt = $(this, ">a").text();
                $("#siteSelector > a").text(liTxt);
                     e.stopPropagation();
               });
                $(document).click(function() {
                     $("a:first", this).removeClass('siteSelect_anchor');
                     $("ul:first",this).removeClass('siteSelect_ul');
                });
            });
        }
```

The dropdown opens up with a click just fine but it will only close if you click again on `#siteSelector`.   I need it to close if a person clicks anywhere on the page which is why I used the `$(document).click(function)` but it does not work and I don't know why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `$(document).click`  outside of all event callback. Otherwise it will get binded every time you click on $("#siteSelector"). and it would not work at first click as  click event is not binded to document yet.

Modified code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqatu/3/)

```
    function clickNav( ) {
    $("#siteSelector").click(function( ) {
        $("a:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_anchor');
        $("ul:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_ul');        
        return false;
    });
    console.log($("#siteSelector li").length);
    $("#siteSelector li").click(function( e ) {
            var liTxt = $("a", this).text();
        console.log(liTxt, $("#siteSelector > a").length);
            $("#siteSelector > a").text(liTxt);
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        });
    $(document).click(function( ) {
         console.log("a");
        $("a:first", $("#siteSelector")).removeClass('siteSelect_anchor');
        $("ul:first", $("#siteSelector")).removeClass('siteSelect_ul');
    });
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work either i.e. the dropdown menu does not disappear when I click anywhere on the page :(

Comment: it works! One problem however is that the portion of my code that replaces the text $("#siteSelector > a").text(liTxt) does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: I also noticed that you added return false; after e.stopPropagation(); ... is that a redundancy?

Comment: @max7 I made the changes for text. You can remove e.stopPropagation(). return false will handle that.

Comment: wow that did it!  Thanks!  One question regarding the console.log statements throughout: are they necessary to keep?  Please forgive my ignorance but I'm not too familiar with the usage of console.log

Comment: @max7 You can remove all of them in your code. I am using them for debugging. console help to show object information

Answer (score 4):

Maybe change the click handler on the document to this:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (! $(event.target).parents().andSelf().is("#siteSelector")) {
        $("a:first", this).removeClass('siteSelect_anchor');
        $("ul:first",this).removeClass('siteSelect_ul');
    }
});
```

Also, move it outside of the click handler for the `#siteSelector` element. It seems like you are binding the handlers for the list items and the document within the `#siteSelector` click handler. This will cause problems. Every time you click on the `#siteSelector` element, you will bind a new copy of the click handlers on the other things, which will result in them being run multiple times, which can cause all sorts of strange undesirable behavior.

Comment: Alas, I tried your idea but no luck here :(  Again, I fully accept that I might not be integrating your solution properly

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here is a fiddle that can be used for modification of my original code: http://jsfiddle.net/VVS3T/9/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/VVS3T/11/

JS

```
function clickNav() {
    $("#siteSelector").click(function() {
        $("a:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_anchor');
        $("ul:first", this).toggleClass('siteSelect_ul');
    });
    $(".item").click(function() {
       $("#siteSelector > a").text($(this).text());
   });
}
$(clickNav);
$(document).bind("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.id != "siteSelectorAnchor" && !$(e.target).hasClass('item')) {
       $("#siteSelector a:first").removeClass('siteSelect_anchor');
       $("#siteSelector ul:first").removeClass('siteSelect_ul');
    }
});
​
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

    </head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="user_info">
       <p>Signed in as <span>max</span></p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li id="siteSelector">
                <a id="siteSelectorAnchor" href="#" class="">Switch to&#9660;</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="item" href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 1</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="item" href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="item" href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="item" href="JavaScript:void(0);">Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/c/portal/logout">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: this is precisely what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `$("body").mouseup()` in the past:

```
var visible = false;

$("#siteSelector").click(function() {
    // your code from above, plus:
    visible = true;
}

$("body").mouseup(function(){ 
    if (visible) {
        $("a:first", this).removeClass('siteSelect_anchor');
        $("ul:first",this).removeClass('siteSelect_ul');
        visible = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.  Here's what I did:

Comment: Got it 90% working: http://jsfiddle.net/j9VnN/. Only thing I got stuck on was making menu disappear when you click on the "switch to" link a second time. Also, I had to make the footer 200px high to catch the `body.mouseUp`.